# Scary movie with a flying killing eel

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am trying to find a movie I saw a little bit of when I was younger.
It's about this human-killing eel-like thing and I can only remember one specific scene.

The scene features one of the main guys sitting on top of a toilet lid to make sure that the eel thing can't come up through it.  At this point, it already killed one of his friends. He is sitting there trying to hold it down but really wants a smoke.  He is so nervous that he drops his matches and tries to reach them without rising from the seat, but ends up falling off and the eel thing comes up.

Immediately before or after this scene, there is another scene of a lot of forest animals running away with blood all over.

Can someone please help me find the title of this movie?

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site. As this is a story identification question, you can also have a look at this [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info).

Comment: Could this be dreamcatcher from 2003? Based the Stephen King novel of the same name. It does feature worm or eel type creatures, there is a character who dies in a toilet and also a scene with animals in the forest covered in blood.There is a clip of the worm creature here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e2q8tGqnOYo is it the one you are thinking of?

Answer (score 8):

This is definitely *[Dreamcatcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreamcatcher_(2003_film))*.

> Suddenly, herds of forest animals flee past their cabin, followed by two military helicopters that announce the area is now quarantined. Jonesy and Beaver return to the cabin to find a trail of blood from the bedroom to the bathroom, where Rick is sitting semi-catatonic on the toilet, which is now covered in blood. Rick is thrown from the toilet, dead into the tub as a three-foot long lamprey like creature writhes and screams in the toilet. Beaver attempts to trap the creature under the toilet lid, but the creature breaks out and kills him.

However, it's toothpicks, not cigarettes, that result in [Beaver](http://dreamcatcher.wikia.com/wiki/Beaver)'s death.

> While Jonesy searched futily for duct tape, Beaver attempted to reach for a lone, untouched toothpick on the floor, seeing as he has a habit for chewing on them. As he did so, whatever was in the toilet tried to bang its way out, making Beaver hold down again.
>
> Finally, Beaver couldn't take it anymore, leaning off the toilet just enough for the creature to get out and knocked Beaver to the ground and go for the back of his neck. When it moved away, Beaver grabbed his glasses and looked at it, only to see a medium-sized worm-looking creature with rows of razor sharp teeth. Fending it off (And losing 4 of his fingers in the process), Jonesy returned with the tape, only to see Beaver batteling the worm. In order to save his friend, he told Jonesy to get out and shut the door. When he did so, the worm attacked and killed The Beav.

Comment: Omg thank you so much i have been searching for this for so long
(the funny part is that my mom told me to watch this movie half a year ago, i just never looked it up)

Comment: @AniToast: You can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.